# PHP authentication not working

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, meta-tags

I'm trying to establish authentication to a profile page with cookies on my login.php. I can't seem to get login.php to authenticate the user.

Here's the code for login.php:

```
if ($result['Password'] != hashPassword($_POST['Password'],$result['SALT'])) {

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Failed to Login, Please Try Again')</script>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0' URL= '/login.php'>";
    exit;
    }

else {
  # A righteous login. First, set the nonce to a value that can be
  # checked in your Account table.
  $nonce = gensym();
  submitDB("UPDATE Customer SET NONCE='" . $nonce . "' WHERE CustomerID=" . $result['CustomerID']);

  # Now set cookies containing credentials that expire in just two
  # hours

  setcookie('CustomerID',$result['CustomerID'],time()+ 60*60*2);
  setcookie('credentials',hash('sha512', $result['CustomerID'] . $nonce),time()+ 60*60*2);

  # Cache name for display on other pages
  setcookie('Name', $result['Name'],time()+ 60*60*2);

  # Refresh this page, which will dispatch me to the right page according to privileges.

  echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0' URL= '/profile.php'>";

  exit;
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! THanks in advance

Comment: `submitDB("UPDATE Customer ...` that looks legit.  Do you letg your users do anything they want to your database from the client side?  If so, it's a security nightmare.

Comment: If you're not getting any errors, we can't help you. You need to do some debugging. What is the result of `hashPassword($_POST['Password'],$result['SALT'])`? What is the value of `$result['Password']`? Are they equal? Do you expect them to be? Is your `submitDB` query working? Is the database updated? Are your cookies being set? You're the only person who can debug this.